# How to use condtional operation in my sql query?

Tags: mysql

[image]Please Check the attachment:

Here I trying to find sum of targets_value fields. but if there record(target_value) is in string format like 2000/3000. I want split them values and add itself.

I want to value add like this using sql query(In My Expample):
500+200+2000+3000+2000+3000.....etc.

I tried it simple query, but it is not possible through below query:

```
SELECT sum(target_value) FROM target
```

Comment: Please post your code...

Comment: Sorry I forgot attachemnt

Comment: @vin, the previous attachment was better! The query is the important bit.

Comment: @JamesWebster: Sorry that was the wrong attachemnt.

Comment: Then you should write your attempted query too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT
 SUM(
  CASE WHEN LOCATE('/', target_value) > 0 
   THEN
    (SUBSTRING_INDEX(target_value, '/', 1) + SUBSTRING_INDEX(target_value, '/', -1))
   ELSE 
    target_value 
   END
 ) AS `total`
FROM target;
```

Based on your example this gives me a sum of 23670